# When Napoleonic wars happened?

Tags: napoleonic-wars

I'm studying History and Napoleonic wars.

Anyway, I think I wrote wrong in my notes. I wrote:R

France against Austria: 1806, France conquered Savoy, Nice and Milan (Milan conquered after the defeat in Lodi).

Napoleone made peace with Austrian: 1807

  French gave to Austria:

  Veneto,

  Istria

  Dalmatia

French get Belgium and Lombardy.

  Napoleone breaks down many old regimes and replace them with republics.
  These republics are:

  Cispadane republic

  Alpine republic

  Ligurian republic

Are these dates correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick review of Wikpedia will show that [Napoleon (1769-1821)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon) was not involved in the [War of the Spanish Succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Ramillies).

[Questions that can be answered by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleonic_Wars) are likely to be closed on H:SE as trivial or basic facts.

Comment: Looks spot on to me.